# Unity scripts failing silently .net 3.5 to .net 4.0

Tags: .net, firebase, unity-game-engine, callback

Today I tried changing my project scripting runtime version from using .net 3.5 equivalent to .net 4.x equivalent. Since then the project has been having all sorts of issues. Scripts are randomly failing. They will be performing some function or other but then stop at seemingly random points. The points that they fail at remain consistent between runs, but can change if I edit the scripts. The weirdest thing about these failures is that no errors are generated in the console. Some errors are logged, but that only occurs if some bit of code run afterwards was dependent on something that was not done when a previous function ended abruptly. I have no idea what could be causing something like this, I haven't even been able to come up with a google search that is remotely helpful. Reverting to 3.5 makes the issues go away, but seeing as 3.5 is depreciated I don't know how long my plugins will continue to support it.

I think this might because caused by the SDK's I use in my project, Firebase Database and Firebase Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing *try / catch* around the problem areas generated an exception in Unity. The errors read:

```
UnityException: EXAMPLE can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
```

Every time a script failed the function calls had originated with a *.ContinueWith()* statement. The failures occurred the first time I tried to access a Unity object in these threads.

Unity objects have never been able to be accessed outside of Unity's main thread. *.ContinueWith()* tasks using the .net 3.5 equivalent scripting runtime version were processed as part of this main thread. Using .net 4.x equivalent they are processed as a separate thread. Frustratingly Unity does not catch this error by default.

Adding a *System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler* to the *.ContinueWith()* can schedule it back into the main thread. Calling and storing *System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()* in the main thread will give you a reference to the main thread for the task scheduler.

```
private void Awake() {
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler taskScheduler = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(task => {
        // Your code here
    }, taskScheduler);
}
```

At first I believed this error was to do with Firebase. That was an incorrect assumption, it just so happened that my Firebase functions contained most of my *.ContinueWith()* function calls.

Comment: Firebase actually makes this a little bit easier with the extension `ContinueWithOnMainThread`. Rather than using a scheduler, it currently maintains a queue of Actions that it dispatches in the Update loop, which makes it a little more predictable where your continuations return. In my own testing with async/await (so likely also with the code above) you do continue between update and late update, but Unity doesn't seem to make any guarantees around that.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension for Firebase's task extensions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a *ton* of ways to work around this issue. I recommend turning your asynchronous code into a [Unity Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and either writing a [CustomYieldInstruction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction.html) or using `yield return new WaitUntil(()=>task.IsComplete);`

I cover this in detail in [this post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) as well as other ways to handle this process (async/await is nice, and you can replace every `ContinueWith` with `ContinueWithOnMainThread` to have your code work exactly as it did before).

The issue is basically that Firebase in Unity 3 uses a library called "Parse" to retrofit Task objects into Unity. It created a sort of action queue that dispatched tasks into the Unity thread's update loop. The extension method [ContinueWithOnMainThread](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) performs this logic perfectly.

Now, why I recommend Coroutines is a little more involved. In Unity, if `Destroy` is called on a Unity object, the C++ bits of that object go away. This creates a sort of minefield of threading related issues if you ever do something like change scenes whilst a Task is running. If you switch to Coroutines, a coroutine cannot continue if the Component that owns it gets cleaned up AND your logic always executes on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

`Task` existed before the async/await keywords were introduced and as such provided ways to execute continuations without relying on the language. Although these methods are still valid to use, we generally recommend that you prefer `async/await` to using `ContinueWith`. `ContinueWith` also does not capture the `SynchronizationContext` and as a result is actually semantically different to `async/await`.

Instead of using

```cs
private void Awake() {
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler taskScheduler = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(task => {
        // Your code here
    }, taskScheduler);
}
```

use this:

```cs
private async Task<int(?)> DosomethingAsync()
{
  var result = await CallDependencyAsync();
  return result + 1;
}
```

What i want to mean its better to prefer `await` over `ContinueWith`.
Anyway, [check this really nice guide](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-await-over-continuewith)